# SQL dynamic pivot for multiple columns

Tags: sql-server

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(Symbol) 
                from Opt 
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')   
set @query = 'SELECT Date,' + @cols + ' from 
         (
            select Date, Symbol, Price
            from Opt 
        )x
        pivot 
        (
            max(Price)
            for Symbol in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p'

execute(@query);
```

I get this from the above code:

```
Symbols(varchar50)       Date     price      quantity
apple              14/11/2016    30       15
banana             14/11/2016    22       20
```

i need like this

```
Date        apple_price  apple_quantity    banana_price  banana_quantity
14/11/2016  30           15                  22          10
```

from above code i get only price

Comment: Your code scares me. Use parameterzation to avoid SQL injection. Also, SQL has sys tables that can make this dynamic and portable (sys.tables and sys.columns come to mind).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a minor twist to your original.  Notice the sub-query/Union All.

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max)
Select  @SQL = Stuff((Select Distinct 
                             ',' + QuoteName(Symbol+'_Price') 
                           + ',' + QuoteName(Symbol+'_Quantity') 
                      From   Opt For XML Path('')),1,1,'')   
Select  @SQL = 'Select Date,' + @SQL + ' 
                From (
                      Select Date,Item=Symbol+''_Price'',Val=Price From Opt
                      Union All
                      Select Date,Item=Symbol+''_Quantity'',Val=Quantity From Opt
                     ) A
                Pivot (max(Val) For Item in (' + @SQL + ') ) p'

Exec(@SQL);
```

Returns

```
Date         apple_Price    apple_Quantity  banana_Price    banana_Quantity
2016-11-14   30             15              22              20
```

Comment: It is working but taking much time can you  modify it

Comment: @Venkat Happy to help

Comment: @Venkat When you say much time.  How much time and how many records in your Opt table?