# T-SQL Pivot Sort Order

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a table that has contact information ordered by sort order and then going down in the column.

Contacts Table: 
[image]

I need to create a table where the emergency contact infomration is sorted by Columns instead of rows:

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: Dynamic pivot.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query

Answer (score 1):

Your dyanmic pivot query should be like in this <kbd>**[demo](http://rextester.com/ROWT8892)**</kbd>

```
declare @cols nvarchar(max);


declare @query nvarchar(max);


select 
    sourceId,
    patientId,
    data,
    cols= concat(col,sortOrder)
into #t
from
    Contacts
    UNPIVOT
    (
    data for col in 
        (
            personalContactType_MisContactTypeId,
            personalContactNameLast,
            personalContactNameFirst
        )
    )up


select @cols= stuff((
                   select distinct  ','+ quotename(cols)
                   from #t 
                   for xml path('')),1,1,'')
select @cols

select @query= 'select * from #t
pivot
( max(data) for cols in ('+@cols+
'))p'

exec (@query)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your [dynamic pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40727283/sql-dynamic-pivot-for-multiple-columns), use `SortOrder` to ORDER BY when creating your column list.